# .jar File Deployment - No Main Method

Tags: java, maven, jar

I am trying to create an executable .jar file for an application, but when I run "java -jar myapp.jar" I get the error:

> Error: Could not find or load main class com.vaadin.app.MainView

I have added the mainClass argument in my pom.xml, and the Manifest.mf shows this:

> Manifest-Version: 1.0
>
> Build-Jdk-Spec: 1.8
>
> Created-By: Maven Archiver 3.4.0
>
> Main-Class: com.vaadin.app.MainView

Is there a reason why it can't find the `Main()` meathod in my class `MainView`?

Comment: *"find the `Main()`"* It is supposed to be (`public static void`) `main(String[])`. No upper case, with arguments. For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: The function is public static void main(String[] args)

Comment: .. Where is the MCVE / SSCCE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in my pom file, it needed the maven-assembly-plugin added with the following configuration:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <archive>
                                <manifest>
                                    <mainClass>
                                        com.vaadin.app.MainView
                                    </mainClass>
                                </manifest>
                            </archive>
                            <descriptorRefs>
                                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                            </descriptorRefs>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
```

Then running the jar-with-dependencies.jar exits with code 0.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issues and for me, the jar file was not properly built.
You can create jar file by going to Run configuration(right-click in eclipse--> maven -->build) and in goals write

clean package -Dmaven.test.skip=true

This will generate your proper jar and this you can run using
java -jar myapp.jar